# How to reinstall Optimization Toolbox in MATLAB？

Tags: matlab

I call Matlab built-in function `fminunc` by

```
[b,fun,flag]    = fminunc(@cov,b0);
```

in the debug mode. The softwoare throw me a `"Reference to non-existent field"` error

```
Reference to non-existent field 'DiffMinChange'.

Error in optimget>optimgetfast (line 102)
    value = options.(name);

Error in optimget (line 25)
    o = optimgetfast(options,name,default);

Error in fminunc (line 201)
options.DiffMinChange = optimget(options,'DiffMinChange',defaultopt,'fast');
```

People in the Mathworks forum suggest me re-hash the toolbox by
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/312355-error-failure-in-initial-user-supplied-objective-function-evaluation-when-using-fminunc

```
rehash toolboxcache
```

But it seems not work. Another way is to reinstall the Optimization Toolbox, but I don't know how to do this, especially how to do this in an effective way. Any suggestion?